# Invisble gwt chart when placed into an HTMLPanel

Tags: javascript, gwt, charts

I'm experiencing a very weird issue and I honestly don't know what is going on...

I'm trying to load a dummy chart in a GWT project. While this works perfectly fine:

```
/**
 * This is the entry point method.
 */
public void onModuleLoad() {
    Window.enableScrolling(false);
    Window.setMargin("0px");
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(getSimpleLayoutPanel());
            // Create the API Loader
    ChartLoader chartLoader = new ChartLoader(ChartPackage.CORECHART);
    chartLoader.loadApi(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            getSimpleLayoutPanel().setWidget(getPieChart());
            drawPieChart();
        }
    });
}
    private SimpleLayoutPanel getSimpleLayoutPanel() {
    if (layoutPanel == null) {
        layoutPanel = new SimpleLayoutPanel();
    }
    return layoutPanel;
}

private Widget getPieChart() {
    if (pieChart == null) {
        pieChart = new PieChart();
    }
    return pieChart;
}

private void drawPieChart() {
    // Prepare the data
    DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();
    dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Name");
    dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Donuts eaten");
    dataTable.addRows(4);
    dataTable.setValue(0, 0, "Michael");
    dataTable.setValue(1, 0, "Elisa");
    dataTable.setValue(2, 0, "Robert");
    dataTable.setValue(3, 0, "John");
    dataTable.setValue(0, 1, 5);
    dataTable.setValue(1, 1, 7);
    dataTable.setValue(2, 1, 3);
    dataTable.setValue(3, 1, 2);

    // Draw the chart
    pieChart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

And I get the expected output:

[image]

When I try to place the chart inside a HTMLPanel:

```
    /**
 * This is the entry point method.
 */
public void onModuleLoad() {
    Window.enableScrolling(false);
    Window.setMargin("0px");

    HTMLPanel html = new HTMLPanel("<div id='container'></div>");
    html.add(getSimpleLayoutPanel(), "container");
    RootPanel.get().add(html);
    html.setVisible(true);

    //        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(getSimpleLayoutPanel());


    // Create the API Loader
    ChartLoader chartLoader = new ChartLoader(ChartPackage.CORECHART);
    chartLoader.loadApi(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            getSimpleLayoutPanel().setWidget(getPieChart());
            drawPieChart();
            getSimpleLayoutPanel().setVisible(true);
            getSimpleLayoutPanel().getWidget().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
```

Results in a white screen, weird enough, if I inspect the DOM with Firebug, I can see the "chart" there...I mean, the svg file that composes the chart:

```
<div aria-hidden="false"><div id="container"><div aria-hidden="false" style="position: relative;"><div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;">&nbsp;</div><div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><div aria-hidden="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><div dir="ltr" style="position: relative; width: 1525px; height: 200px;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><svg style="overflow: hidden;" height="200" width="1525"><defs id="defs"></defs><rect fill="#ffffff" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" height="200" width="1525" y="0" x="0"></rect><g><rect fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" height="87" width="453" y="38" x="934"></rect><g><rect fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" height="15" width="453" y="38" x="934"></rect><g><text fill="#222222" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" font-size="15" font-family="Arial" y="50.75" x="955" text-anchor="start">Michael</text></g><rect fill="#3366cc" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" height="15" width="15" y="38" x="934"></rect></g><g><rect fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" height="15" width="453" y="62" x="934"></rect><g><text fill="#222222" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" font-size="15" font-family="Arial" y="74.75" x="955" text-anchor="start">Elisa</text></g><rect fill="#dc3912" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" height="15" width="15" y="62" x="934"></rect></g><g><rect fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" height="15" width="453" y="86" x="934"></rect><g><text fill="#222222" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" font-size="15" font-family="Arial" y="98.75" x="955" text-anchor="start">Robert</text></g><rect fill="#ff9900" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" height="15" width="15" y="86" x="934"></rect></g><g><rect fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" height="15" width="453" y="110" x="934"></rect><g><text fill="#222222" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" font-size="15" font-family="Arial" y="122.75" x="955" text-anchor="start">John</text></g><rect fill="#109618" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" height="15" width="15" y="110" x="934"></rect></g></g><g><path fill="#3366cc" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" d="M525,100L525,38A62,62,0,0,1,584.6331898767148,116.96710538446915L525,100A0,0,0,0,0,525,100"></path></g><g><path fill="#109618" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" d="M525,100L483.23087009391344,54.181447132319164A62,62,0,0,1,525,38L525,100A0,0,0,0,0,525,100"></path></g><g><path fill="#ff9900" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" d="M525,100L465.36681012328523,116.96710538446915A62,62,0,0,1,483.2308700939135,54.18144713231911L525,100A0,0,0,0,0,525,100"></path></g><g><path fill="#dc3912" stroke-width="1" stroke="#ffffff" d="M525,100L584.6331898767148,116.96710538446915A62,62,0,0,1,465.36681012328523,116.96710538446918L525,100A0,0,0,0,0,525,100"></path><text fill="#ffffff" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" font-size="15" font-family="Arial" y="140.04361653961504" x="504.5" text-anchor="start">41.2%</text></g><g></g></svg></div></div><div style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 210px; left: 1535px; white-space: nowrap; font-family: Arial; font-size: 15px;">John</div><div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Now as you can see, for some reason is set to "hidden"....any idea why???? Going nuts with this!

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting an explicit width and height to your HTMLPanel and to your SimpleLayoutPanel. Since HTMLPanel does not implement RequiresResize and ProvidesResize, you need to set an explicit size.

For resizing to work properly, you must have "*an unbroken hierarchy between all widgets that implement RequiresResize and the RootLayoutPanel, which listens for any changes (such as the browser window resizing) that could affect the size of widgets in the hierarchy*".

For more info see: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Resize

Comment: Hi, no luck, still can't see a thing...my intention is to add the SimpleLayoutPanel that contains the chart to an existing panel. That's why I was using HTMLPanel. This is just a test, but I want to integrate it in a real app if it works, where I have an exisiting htmlPanel where I want to throw the SimpleLayoutPanel. In this app is working right now but with a VerticalPanel. Since I want it to be "responsive" to the viewport size, I'm trying to use a SimpleLayoutPanel instead

Comment: Did you also try setting an explicit size to the SimpleLayoutPanel?

Comment: Hi again, while this effectively makes the chart appear, I'm losing the "automatic chart resize" capability from the original snippet. Is this because I'm setting height and width manually or because the HTMLPanel in which I placed the SimpleLayoutPanel does not listen to onResize events???

Comment: Because HTMLPanel breaks the RequiresResize hierarchy, and also because your second snippet is using RootPanel instead of RootLayoutPanel. See my edited answer.

Comment: So, only LayoutPanels can be used? Reading the doc provided, looks like 1) I can create a custom HTMLPanel that implements ProvidesResize, since the HTMLPanel will be the parent widget of my LayoutPanel or...2) Use a ResizeComposite, never used Composites yet...what would be your choice?

Comment: After some more reading, I think that using RootLayoutPanel requires a careful design from start. I'm gonna have to rethink my whole design again...anyway, thanks for pointing that out David!